# Which node_modules my project actually use?

Tags: node.js

We had the following problem:

The project is install under `/home/node/project`

where `project` is a soft link to `/home/node/deploy/project{version}`

The `package.json` is under `/home/node/`

We did `npm i` in `/home/node/project` which should have found the `package.json` under `/home/node/` and build the `node_module` has expected.

But for some unknown reason, about a month ago, someone created a `package.json` under `/home/node/deploy`

Therefor the `npm i` build a new `node_module` under `/home/node/deploy` which was defected

Although we suspected that the code is using the wrong `node_module` we couldn't figure out which `node_module` the code actually use and wasted long time until we realize that a defected `node_module` was created in the wrong directory

So I would like to know if there is a way to know which `node_modules` my project actually use at run time?

Answer (score -1):

Delete one of the node_modules folders and run your code. If your code is running without any errors, then it may mean that it is using the other node_modules folder.